# Mtom Java EE DataHandler - new thread creation

Tags: java, performance, web-services, jakarta-ee, mtom

I am using MTOM to stream the content of some file to the client side via a WebSevice.

The front end call a WS on a backend server and the file is streamed to the client.

However the app is a Java EE environment (WebLogic), and as far as I know it is not allowed (or considered a good practice to create new threads) but the code of the DataHandler used by MTOM does that:

```
   // there is none but the default^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  252               final DataContentHandler fdch = dch;
  253   
  254               // from bill s.
  255               // ce n'est pas une pipe!
  256               //
  257               // NOTE: This block of code needs to throw exceptions, but
  258               // can't because it is in another thread!!! ARG!
  259               //
  260               final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
  261               PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream(pos);
  262               new Thread(
  263                          new Runnable() {
  264                   public void run() {
  265                       try {
  266                           fdch.writeTo(object, objectMimeType, pos);
  267                       } catch (IOException e) {
  268   
  269                       } finally {
  270                           try {
  271                               pos.close();
  272                           } catch (IOException ie) { }
  273                       }
  274                   }
  275               },
  276                         "DataHandler.getInputStream").start();
  277               ins = pin;
```

http://www.docjar.org/html/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.java.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html

So is using MTOM with streaming safe in Java EE? The fact that new threads aren't created by the container might not be dangerous at all?

Comment: Strange that after so many years, this thread creation and silent failure behavior is still not fixed in `jakarta.activation-api` as well